# Linebreak in measure not resulting in a linebreak in Data label Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this DAX code for a measure that I use as a Data label:

```
Event Tooltip = 

VAR __CurrentDate = MAX(Lookuptable_Calendar[Date])
VAR __Events = CONCATENATEX(EventData2, IF(
    __CurrentDate IN CALENDAR(EventData2[StartDate], EventData2[EndDate]), 
    VAR __Placeholder = AVERAGE(EventData2[EventID]) // Does nothing
    RETURN
    EventData2[Description]),  UNICHAR(10)
)
RETURN __Events
```

Notice the Delimiter `UNICHAR(10)`, which should yield a linebreak.
However if I use it in my graph, the Data label does not include a linebreak:
[image: linebreak not working]

The event data that I use:

| EventID | StartDate | EndDate | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-30 | 2023-07-03 | Corporate Event |
| 2 | 2023-06-30 | 2023-06-30 | VM! |

Does anyone know how I can get the linebreak to work in the Data label?

Comment: No the reply you provided is not a solution to the problem (it's stating that there is no support for such functionality yet). The question remains open until a solution is implemented or a workaround is discovered @DavideBacci.

Comment: You should stop deleting comments / reply's @DavideBacci, it's not helpful.

Comment: You said the reply was no help so I removed it. That is standard at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I voted to close as the question obviously cannot be answered to your satisfaction so it seems pointless to have it here. There is no work around and the functionality doesn't exist. We don't work for Microsoft and are volunteering our free time to help people who are stuck with Power BI problems. I don't want other problem solvers to waste their time on this when others need valuable help.

Comment: Why would it be pointless? If someone else encounters the same problem they would find this topic (with a bit of luck) - and if you left your previous reply they would know there is no solution in place currently.

Comment: They would see the question and zero solved or upvoted answers which is no help. 
If you found the solution provided helpful, it is customary to upvote it for the benefit of others.

Comment: Hard to upvote something that is deleted! :-)

Comment: Undeleted for you

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet supported but is on the road map (source: I'm a community rep for the PBI core visuals revamp).